# I will be going to Sweden for business. Can I visit London from Sweden and how much will a UK visa cost?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, applications, sweden

I reside in India, but will be going to Sweden for business purposes. Can I visit London by applying for a visa from Sweden?

Comment: Visas take time. Will you be residing in Sweden for a time or is it a short trip?

Comment: If you're planning to go to London and then back to Sweden, make sure your Swedish visa allows multiple entries.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to wait until you are in Sweden to apply for the visa?

Comment: Note that you can visit anywhere in Schengen (such as Paris or Amsterdam) with the visa you already have. Of course, as a British citizen, I'm not going to dissuade you from coming to the UK if that's what you want!

Comment: @DavidRicherby but isn't specifically that `dissuade you from coming to the UK ` that Brexit is all about? :)

Comment: @marcellomiorelli The asker wishes to visit London and most people in London voted remain. :-P

Answer (score 13):

You can apply for a UK visa from any location where there is a visa application centre (VAC), it does not have to be from your country of residence, so yes, you can apply from Sweden. A Standard Visitor visa costs £93 and typically takes up to 3 weeks to process (it can take longer in some cases) https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

It should be possible to complete the application online in India and book a biometric appointment at a VAC in Sweden, however if you’re not planning to be in Sweden for at least 3 weeks afterwards there’s a risk you won’t get the decision, and thus your passport, back in time. There may be a ‘keep my passport’ option when you apply that would solve this, although there’s still a risk that you wouldn’t get the decision in time.